# How to clamp a stock in AnyLogic?

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic, clamp

I want to clamp a stock between -10 and 10 in AnyLogic.

I currently use an own defined java function for this. Is there any better solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

there's a big set of distributions in anylogic

for example
`uniform(-10,10)` will give you a random value between -10 and 10

Answer (score 1):

If you want to explore all possible random distributions, put your cursor into a code field. Then, at the top of AnyLogic, the tiny icon called "[Distribution Wizard](https://anylogic.help/anylogic/stochastic/choose-pdf.html#choose-probability-distribution-wizard)" pops up:
[image]

Play around and it will write the correct code to apply it.